# envMap lighting not working if metalness value is 0

Tags: three.js, textures, lighting

I'm using a spherical projected image as an environmental light for my mesh but it only lights the mesh properly when metalness value is set to 1.

---

Metalness = 1

[image]

---

Metalness = 0

Light rendered here is the spot light and ambient light but envMap doesn't seem to do anything here.

[image]

Do we really need to set metalness to 1 for envMap to work or am I doing this all wrong?

```
suzanne.material.metalness = 0;
suzanne.material.visible = true;
suzanne.material.envMap = textures[0];
suzanne.material.envMapIntensity = 1.5;
suzanne.material.envMap.mapping = THREE.SphericalReflectionMapping;
```

Comment: You need to post more code. What is `textures[0]`?

Comment: Metalness should be irrelevant to whether environment maps work or not.

Comment: I have an array of textures loaded thru TextureLoader and it is used for the envMap. I don't that would matter since the only difference in code for both of the renders are the metalness.